# Confusing about permalink

Tags: permalinks, homepage

I'm nubie in WP and I have some problems but the annoying for me is the default permalink. When tried to visit my site from top of the dashboard link, it says "mydomain.com/home" instead mydomain.com. So it directs me to 'NOT FOUND' page.
Please help

FYI, it's still installed in my dev.domain.com site.

Comment: Have you set your frontpage in Settings->Reading?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your settings under `Settings > General`.  Is your `Site Address (URL)` set to `http://dev.domain.com`?  The next place I would look would be `Settings > Permalinks`.